# What is a clean way to copy a SQL table with more than 1000 rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the question "How to copy table with more than 1000 rows" is already asked. I have read a lot about it and the different solutions like:

- use export to excel and than import in new table
- use UNION ALL (but not recommend)
- use bulkreader
- export to file and import
- etc.

All the solutions sounding like a workaround. I am asking myself, is there no "official", clean way to do it?

Thank you.

Edit:

- SELECT INTO was tried
- INSERT INTO was tried
- Using sql MS MGM studio
- using HeidiSQL

Working on a MS SQL Server 13.0.4001.0

Comment: Why not simply use select into? But as for an "official" way there isn't. There is never a single way to do anything. And generally speaking copying tables is not a good idea anyway. There are times it makes sense for testing and such but as a general practice it is big red flag that something is wrong with the design.

Comment: And what is your definition of "clean"? That has no common meaning in this context.

Comment: You can try anyone and see what is the issue and the differences between new and old table data. I think all the above available options are good. What is your case study related to the problem statement?

Comment: Why do you say `UNION ALL` is not recommended? To do what?

Comment: Copy from where to where?

Comment: `Export to Excel then import into a new table` Ok satan.

Comment: You can use `SELECT INTO` to copy data into a new auto-generated table. That table won't have any keys or indexes though. Or you can use `INSERT ... SELECT` to select data from one table and insert it into another. There's absolutely no reason to export such a tiny amount of data to a file or use any kind of bulk operation

Comment: I voted to close as "unclear" not "opinion based" because `SELECT ... INTO`  and `INSERT INTO` work fine for more than a thousand rows so this seems based on a misunderstanding

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest and fastest solution with T-SQL would be [`into`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select *
into [destination table]
from [source table]
```

This will copy your data into a [destination table]. Be mindful of the [`remarks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) and limitations in the documentation regarding this keyword.

Comment: Also permissions, but yes, this is usually the easiest way to copy the **data**.

Comment: In my case works just for less than 1000 rows, isn't this the usual behaviour?

Comment: @PatrickRainer what does `in my case` mean? INSERT..SELECT and SELECT..INTO work for *far more* that 1000 rows. 1000 is no data at all. Even 1M isn't big data. Big, for modern ... *laptops*... would start at 500M. Servers work with TBs of data

Comment: @PatrickRainer that would be an important detail to add to your question. Are just the "first" 1000 rows copied or nothing?

Comment: @PatrickRainer - there is no such limitation for `SELECT ..INTO` how are you verifying that only 1,000 rows are copied? If you are doing a `SELECT` maybe the tool you are using just returns the first 1,000. e.g. this is the default for right click and select in SSMS

Comment: The first 1000 are copied and I am using select into or insert into

Comment: @PatrickRainer At this point, your question is becoming vague. You need to provide more details on what you're trying to achieve if this solution doesn't solve a specific problem. If your "problem" is simply a general question on how to copy over data, the items you've listed are the "official" ways to achieve this. There is no "official one way" to do anything in SQL Server.

Comment: Ok thanks neverthless. Will do tomorrow.